# tokenize the string in c programming of desired length?

Tags: c

How to tokenize the string (stored in the `fgets()` function) into various desired sizes?
the values doesn't have any delimiting characters in between(`\n,,,:,:,`etc.) them.
the string is

> "ABCD 1234 EFG56H1.223.445.66    J"

i want the resultant tokens should be looks like

> "ABCD" " 1234" " "/*reading the space as a character*/ "EF" "56" "H"
>   "1.22"/*(.)dot also a character*/ "3.44" "5.66"

How to do this with `strtok` function?

This question is actually for extracting the ATOM record from the PDB file using C.

Comment: Don't use `strtok` for that. If you know the length, use it, `strncpy(dest,src+off,len);` for example.

Comment: Don't use strncpy(). If you know the length, use `memcpy(dst, src+off, len); dst[len] = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use strok.  You'll need to write your own substring function, but something like this would work:

```
int position = 0;
int i = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfColumnWidths; i++) {
    if (columnWidths[i] <= 0) {
        # Error, column width must be greater than 0.
    }

    char* columnVal = substring(lineOfText, position, position + columnWidths[i]);
    # store columnVal in some final array, e.g. finalArray[i] = columnVal

    position = position + columnWidths[i];
}
```

columnWidths is an array of integers where the ith value is width of the ith column.  So for you it'd be:

```
[4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, etc...]
```

Comment: What the lengthofcilumnwidths stand for? is it the length of the string which we are going to brake into substrings?

Comment: substring function is not working.it showing"undefined reference to substring"

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't very clear.  lengthOfColumnWidths is the length of your columnWidths array.  It's also the number of columns you want ultimately.

Comment: As for the substring method, you need to write your own as I said, where you specify the string you want the subset of as well as the start and end positions.  As wildplasser said, use `memcpy(dst, src+off, len); dst[len] = 0;`.

Comment: This substring function here (http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/extract-substring-from-string-in-c-432620/#post3315654) seems to be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply sscanf like

```
char a[100],b[100],c[100],d[100],e[100],f[100],g[100],h[100];
sscanf("ABCD 1234 EFG56H1.223.445.66 J","%s%s%2s%*1s%2s%1s%4s%4s%4s",a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h);
```